# Sphinx error "AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1."

Tags: sphinx, autodoc

I use sphinx to auto generate documents. When I ran "make html", it raised the following error.

```
error: AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1.
```

I found a related article in http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/28/accessinit-hash-collision-3-both-1-and-1/. It said that it's the different ways of import PIL that result in the collision. I do exactly as this article said,  patch Docutils and Pygments, but I still got the above error.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It can be caused usually by seeming multiple installation of `PIL` due to virtualenv. Packages `Image` and `PIL.Image` are found on different paths in virtualenv although they are finally the same after resolving the symbolic link.

A universal solution for possible causes is to change the PYTHONPATH in order to they are found on the same paths.
Usually add the directory where PIL is found in vitrualenv to the beginning of PYTHONPATH.